# discord.js get message's id and delete it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

When a user joins the server, the bot sends a welcome message, i want to take that welcome message's ID and make the bot delete it if the users leaves after he joins. I tried to save the message's id in a variable and make the bot delete the message when the user leaves but without success. I already took a look at the docs, but I really can't understand how to make it.

Comment: Could you please post the code you've written which was not successful? It's helpful to provide others with some context, especially if it includes a way to reproduce what you've already tried. Check out this Stack Overflow article on how to ask a great question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: i lost the code i tried, anyway, it was wrong, i tried to fetch the message to a variable and then take that variable id and delete the mesagge. I have no problem on asking a great question, you can see the others on my profile, but in this chase i really don't know even how to start.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you would have to store the id of the welcome message and the user that it is tied to (ideally put this in an object). And when the user leaves you would use those values to delete that message.

Example code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const welcomeChannel = client.channels.find("name","welcome"); // Welcome is just an example 
let welcomes = [];

client.on('message', (message) => {
    if(message.channel.name === 'welcome') {
        const welcomeObj = { id: message.id, user: message.mentions.users.first().username };
        welcomes.push(welcomeObj);
    }
});

client.on('guildMemberRemove', (member) => {
    welcomes.forEach(welcome, () => {
        if(welcome.user === member.user.username) {
            welcomeChannel.fetchMessage(welcome.id).delete();
        }
    });
});
```

This only works if the welcome message includes a mention to the user so make sure that's in the welcome message.

Also I can't test this code myself at the moment so let me know if you encounter any problems.

Answer (score 1):

1. Define an object to hold the welcome messages by guild and user. You may want to use a JSON file or database (I'd highly recommend the latter) to store them more reliably.
2. When a user joins a guild...

   - Send your welcome message.
   - Pair the the message's ID with the user within the guild inside of the object.
3. When a member leaves the guild...

   - Fetch their welcome message.
   - Delete the message from Discord and the object.

Example setup:

```js
const welcomeMessages = {};
```

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
  const welcomeChannel = client.channels.get('channelIDHere');
  if (!welcomeChannel) return console.error('Unable to find welcome channel.');

  try {
    const message = await welcomeChannel.send(`Welcome, ${member}.`);

    if (!welcomeMessages[member.guild.id]) welcomeMessages[member.guild.id] = {};
    welcomeMessages[member.guild.id][member.id] = message.id;
  } catch(err) {
    console.error('Error while sending welcome message...\n', err);
  }
});
```

```js
client.on('guildMemberRemove', async member => {
  const welcomeChannel = client.channels.get('channelIDHere');
  if (!welcomeChannel) return console.error('Unable to find welcome channel.');

  try {
    const message = await welcomeChannel.fetchMessage(welcomeMessages[member.guild.id][member.id]);
    if (!message) return;

    await message.delete();
    delete welcomeMessages[member.guild.id][member.id];
  } catch(err) {
    console.error('Error while deleting existing welcome message...\n', err);
  }
});
```